# Javascript Objects: Accessing object variables from methods

Tags: javascript, json, oop

Quick question, and one I am yet to work out on my own. I'll start with an example.

```
object = {
    somevariable: true,
    someothervariable:31,
    somefunction: function(input){
        if (somevariable === true){
            return someothervariable+input;
        }
    }
}

object.somefunction(3);
```

Obviously this won't work. Do I have to say `object.somevariable` and `object.someothervariable` or is there a means of referring to variables that are part of the local object, without referring to the object explicitly?

Thanks

Gausie

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the special keyword [`this`](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html), which refers to the object a function was invoked on:

```
var thing = {
    somevariable: true,
    someothervariable:31,
    somefunction: function(input){
        if (this.somevariable === true){
            return this.someothervariable+input;
        }
    }
}
thing.somefunction(3);

var otherThing = {
    somevariable: true,
    someothervariable:'foo',
    amethod: thing.somefunction
};
otherThing.amethod('bar');
```

Be careful about using variable names like "object". JS is case-sensitive, so it won't collide with the intrinsic `Object`, but you might get into trouble in other languages.

Comment: This seems obvious, why did I not try it?

Comment: of course, this will work only inside functions... if you have smth like var o = {a:1,b:this.a}; this will definetly won't work

Answer (score 1):

When adding "this" it works for me.

```
var o = {
    somevariable: true,
    someothervariable:31,
    somefunction: function(input){
        if (this.somevariable === true){
            return this.someothervariable+input;
        }
    }
}

alert(o.somefunction(3));
```